# While loop does not produce pipeline output

Tags: powershell

It appears that a While loop does not produce an output that can continue in the pipeline. I need to process a large (many GiB) file. In this trivial example, I want to extract the second field, sort on it, then get only the unique values. What am I not understanding about the While loop and pushing things through the pipeline?

In the *NIX world this would be a simple:

```
cut -d "," -f 2 rf.txt | sort | uniq
```

In PowerShell this would be not quite as simple.

The source data.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> Get-Content .\rf.txt
these,1,there
lines,3,paragraphs
are,2,were
```

The script.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> Get-Content .\rf.ps1
$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("$(Get-Location)\rf.txt")

while ($line = $sr.ReadLine()) {
    Write-Verbose $line
    $v = $line.split(',')[1]
    Write-Output $v
} | sort

$sr.Close()
```

The output.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> .\rf.ps1
At C:\src\powershell\rf.ps1:7 char:3
+ } | sort
+   ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

Answer (score 2):

Making it a bit more complicated than it needs to be.  You have a CSV without headers. The following should work:

```
Import-Csv .\rf.txt -Header f1,f2,f3 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty f2 -Unique | Sort-Object
```

Comment: Will Import-Csv act like Get-Content and try to read the entire file into memory? If so, that won't handle large files.

Comment: @Liturgist my understanding is that `Get-Content` (when called without the `-Raw` switch) does not read the entire file into memory. If you were seeing that behavior, it was likely due to you piping it to `Sort-Object` (`sort` is an alias for the latter); see my answer for why.

Comment: apologies for the delay in responding back. `Import-Csv` will read the file one line at a time. You do not need to worry about doing a separate `Get-Content`.  https://technet.microsoft.com/library/2a767ced-0fc9-4896-a8f0-2c5bdee49910(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: @Nasir he'll have the same "problem" though as long as he's still piping to `Sort-Object`

Answer (score 2):

Nasir's workaround looks like the way to go here.

If you want to know what was going wrong in your code, the answer is <s>that `while` loops (and `do`/`while`/`until` loops) don't consistently return values to the pipeline the way that other statements in PowerShell do</s> (actually that is true, and I'll keep the examples of that, but scroll down for the real reason it wasn't working for you).

`ForEach-Object` -- a cmdlet, not a built-in language feature/statement; does return objects to the pipeline.

```
1..3 | % { $_ }
```

`foreach` -- statement; does return.

```
foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i }
```

`if`/`else` -- statement; does return.

```
if ($true) { 1..3 }
```

`for` -- statement; does return.

```
for ( $i = 0 ; $i -le 3 ; $i++ ) { $i }
```

`switch` -- statement; does return.

```
switch (2)
{
    1 { 'one' }
    2 { 'two' }
    3 { 'three' }
}
```

---

But for some reason, these other loops seem to act unpredictably.

Loops forever, returns `$i` (`0` ; no incrementing going on).

```
$i = 0; while ($i -le 3) { $i }
```

Returns nothing, but `$i` does get incremented:

```
$i = 0; while ($i -le 3) { $i++ }
```

If you wrap the expression inside in parentheses, it seems it does get returned:

```
$i = 0; while ($i -le 3) { ($i++) }
```

---

But as it turns out (I'm learning a bit as I go here), `while`'s strange return semantics have nothing to do with your error; you just can't pipe statements into functions/cmdlets, regardless of their return value.

```
foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i } | measure
```

will give you the same error.

You can "get around" this by making the entire statement a sub-expression with `$()`:

```
$( foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i } ) | measure
```

That would work for you in this case. Or in your `while` loop instead of using `Write-Output`, you could just add your item to an array and then sort it after:

```
$arr = @()

while ($line = $sr.ReadLine()) {
    Write-Verbose $line
    $v = $line.split(',')[1]
    $arr += $v
} 

$arr | sort
```

I know you're dealing with a large file here, so maybe you're thinking that by piping to `sort` line by line you'll be avoiding a large memory footprint. In many cases piping does work that way in PowerShell, but the thing about sorting is that you need the whole set to sort it, so the `Sort-Object` cmdlet will be "collecting" each item you pass to it anyway and then do the actual sorting in the end; I'm not sure you can avoid that at all. Admittedly letting `Sort-Object` do that instead of building the array yourself might be more efficient depending on how its implemented, but I don't think you'll be saving much on RAM.

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
Get-Content -Path C:\temp\rf.txt | select @{Name="Mycolumn";Expression={($_ -split "," )[1]}} | select Mycolumn -Unique | sort
```